# Matrix Layout, control with height 100% does not cover whole height of cell

Tags: sapui5

I want to define the following arrangement of controls:

```
VBox----------- TextArea---
! TextField   ! !         !
! TextField   ! !         !
! TextField   ! !         !
! TextField   ! !         !
! TextField   ! !         !
--------------- -----------
```

On the left some control (here: VBox with content) and on the right a text area that covers the whole height. Result: should be that the text area has the same height as the VBox.

I tried to do this with MatrixLayout + assigning a height of 100% to the text area, but fail. The 100%-definition for the height of the text area is not interpreted the way I want...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>SAPUI5 Testing</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons">
    </script>
    <script>
        // VBox for the left side, containing 10 text fields                
        var vvb = new sap.m.VBox();
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            var vtf = new sap.ui.commons.TextField ();
            vtf.setValue("TextField");
            vtf.setWidth("100%");
            vvb.addItem(vtf);
        }

        // TextArea for the right side
        var vta = new sap.ui.commons.TextArea();
        vta.setWidth("100px");
        vta.setHeight("100%"); // <== I want the text area to be as high as the cell
        vta.setValue("Text Area");

        // Matrix + one row        
        var vma = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed:false});
        vma.createRow(vvb,vta);

        vma.placeAt("uiArea");
     </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result looks like:

```
VBox----------- 
! TextField   ! 
! TextField   ! TextArea---
! TextField   ! !         !
! TextField   ! -----------
! TextField   !
---------------
```

Has someone some idea how to layout the controls, so that the text area covers the whole height of the cell? (...of course I do not want to define a pixel height...!)

Thanks!

Comment: The result looks 100% height to me, see http://jsbin.com/tosezumatelo/1/edit

Comment: Ooooh - I see: this is an incompatibility issued between browsers.

Comment: It does work on Chrome, but does not work on Firefox (32.0.2) and does not work on Internet Explorer (11). - With Safari I cannot tell...

Answer (score 0):

try to change the order of your codelines. i think you have to set the height *after* creating the row:

```
vma.createRow(vvb,vta);
vta.setHeight("100%");
```

by the way: did you get an exception from createRow(...)? i think createRow(...) allows only one parameter:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout.html#createRow

Comment: The behavior is still the same after changing the sequence. I would be very surprised if the sequence was such relevant... - And: yes, you may pass a list of controls into createRow method.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I found:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>SAPUI5 Testing</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Matrix + one row        
        var vma = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
          layoutFixed:false
        });
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
          if (i == 0) {
            var oCell1 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell();
            oCell1.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
              value : "TextField",
              width : "100%"
            }));

            var oCell2 = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell({
              // this is the solution for your desired layout
              rowSpan : 10,
              height : "100%"
            });
            oCell2.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.TextArea({
              width : "100px",
              height : "100%",
              value : "Text Area"
            }));

            vma.createRow(oCell1, oCell2);

          } else {
            vma.createRow(new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
              value : "TextField",
              width : "100%"
            }));
          }
        }

        vma.placeAt("uiArea");
     </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/xoyakicarora/1/edit?html,output